# How to prevent "Look Up" functionality from showing link previews?

Tags: macos, look-up

As you know Apple just updated the look up function and added previews of the link you highlighted. As a non-native I often use look up to see the meaning of a word. When the word appears as a link, or within a link highlight shows the preview instead of dictionary.

I was wondering if there is a way to switch between them or disable preview options.

Answer (score 2):

No definitive answer, but I do have a workaround for you.

Select the link including a whitespace before or after it, then use the look up function on the whitespace part of the selection.

**Update:** you can also look it up by selecting it and then right clicking a few pixels next to it (see picture). I find the quickest way to do this is right clicking the link to select it, than right clicking again right next to it to make the 'Look up' function appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three-finger taps only preview full links in Safari. In other browsers, the gesture looks up the tapped word in Dictionary.

One option, then, would simply be to use a different browser – though, of course, there are many other factors influencing that decision.